# How do I create a repository method that searches for an embedded value?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an embeddable class to hold a reference ID because I don't want to repeat the details of the column in every JPA entity.

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class BusinessReference {
    private static final int LENGTH = 64;

    @Column(
        columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(64)",
        length = LENGTH,
        updatable = false,
        nullable = false,
        unique = true)
    @Size(min = LENGTH, max = LENGTH)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[!-~]+$")
    private String referenceId;

}
```

Now I have an entity

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Sample {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(
        updatable = false,
        nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Embedded
    private BusinessReference businessReference;

}
```

What I want to do is create a generic interface that would allow me to search by reference ID that I can use to extend another `CrudRepository` if needed.  Note the parameter I want is the String rather than the object.

```
public interface BusinessReferenceRepository<T> {
    Optional<T> getByBusinessReference(String referenceId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a `default` that would allow me to call it by the original type.

```
public interface BusinessReferenceRepository<T> {
    Optional<T> getByBusinessReference(BusinessReference businessReference);

    default Optional<T> getByBusinessReference(String referenceId) {
        return getByBusinessReference(new BusinessReference(referenceId));
    }
}
```